# MDX Case Statement with different Measure outputs

Tags: ssas, case, mdx

I am trying to write a simple CASE statement in MDX that returns Measure values from different Fact tables based on a particular dimension type as below -

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Amount] AS
CASE  [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].CURRENTMEMBER 
        WHEN [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[1] THEN [Measures].[Amount - Fact Sale]
      WHEN [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[2] THEN [Measures].[Amount - Fact Sale]
      WHEN [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[11] THEN [Measures].[Amount - Fact Usage]
END
```

I am then using the [Measures].[Amount] in my MDX. Problem here is I am not getting the required value for Type 11. If I move my the when case to first line, I am getting the value for usage and sometimes for Sale. A wierd behavior I am not able to understand.

Can somebody help?

Comment: MDX has the IIF conditional which might be usuful in this sitatuon too.

Comment: Use...     CASE WHEN  [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[1] THEN ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with CELL CALCULATION:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Amount] AS [Measures].[Amount - Fact Sale]
CELL CALCULATION [A] FOR '({[Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[1], [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[2]}, [Measures].[Amount])' As ([Measures].[Amount - Fact Sale])
CELL CALCULATION [B] FOR '({[Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[11]}, [Measures].[Amount])' As ([Measures].[Amount - Fact Usage])
```

Comment: Thanks Noe, that worked perfectly. Any idea why CASE statement was failing?

Comment: Maybe, you must use the other syntax with the IS function: CASE WHEN  [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].CURRENTMEMBER  IS [Dim Trx Type].[Trx Type Id].&[1] THEN ....